# Get substring in lightning component with force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, string

I am using force:recordData in a lightning component to get the data by passing in the Opportunity id. It works without any issues. However, I would like to change the opportunity stagename value from let's say "01-Prospecting" to just "Prospecting" by leaving out the numbers and the hyphen.  The string functions I saw for the lightning components don't seem to help to get a substring out of a string.

Below is the code:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler" 
                  recordId="{!v.opp.Id}"
                  fields="Id,LastModifiedDate,Name,Account.Name,StageName"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}" />
```

I would like to get a substring out of the {!v.simpleRecord.StageName}.

I tried using the init handler to set a different attribute with the substring from the controller method (doInit), but it seems the record data is fetched after the initialization of the component and I get null for the v.simpleRecord.

Please let me know if the question is not clear and I will try to post some examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the record may not be initialized during your component's `init` event handler. Instead, you want to add a `change` handler on `v.simpleRecord` and perform any logic necessary when that variable changes (due to the record being loaded).

Comment: Thanks @dsharrison. It worked. I used another string attribute to store the substring and then display that value.